# Installing MS SQL Server on system with Plesk

Tags: sql-server, vps, plesk

If I get a VPS server, which has Microsoft Windows Server 2008 (maybe 2012) and Plesk 11 installed on it, do I just install MS SQL Server and Plesk will automatically recognize that SQL Server is installed and use it, or is there some special Plesk configuration necessary to tie Plesk 11 to the new MS SQL Server?

Also, does MS SQL Server Express play a part in that, if the VPS comes with it? I presume that I should uninstall SQL Server Express first if it comes with the VPS.  If so, does that present a problem with confusing Plesk 11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server 2008(Express) and 2012(Express) included in Plesk 11 distributive and can be installed with Plesk.

If you have SQL server installed separately from Plesk on single server, you can just add(register) this server in Plesk GUI(In Tools & settings > Database Servers). All what you need just sa's password.

I recommend to register local MSSQL server as "localhost", in this case Plesk will understand that it's "local" DB server, because some features like Backup of databases may don't work in case of remote DB server.

Uninstall of SQL server doesn't confuse Plesk.

May I Ask you a question? Why did you need uninstall express SQL server? Which exact limitation of Express edition not satisfied by your requirements? I just wonder why it can be needed on shared hosting?

Comment: Of course you can ask a question. I am contemplating obtaining a VPS, as my current shared hosting environment has limitations (only one static IP, slow MS SQL, limited MS SQL databases, and most importantly of all is that I cannot change the cache dependency setting required by VevoCart Multi-Store). Although I have no clue which is a good VPS, the one that I am contemplating has the option to install SQL Server Express or to not. I consider it a waste of space, as my MSDN Subscription comes with SQL Server and VPS charges by space. It is not uninstall as rather not install in the fist place.

Comment: Well, if you will obtain a VPS with SQL Express and it's fits in your requirements(I mean that you don't need any SQL server features which absent in Express edition), why to do stay with this version?

Comment: I could. I did briefly look at MSDN's comparison chart yesterday showing the various features, however I did not understand from a lay programmer's point of view what the practical differences were. Heck, I was trying to decide if I need Standard of Enterprise. MSDN includes both, just I want to minimize disk space usage. The question augments to how as a programmer do I know which version I need? You asked a great question and one that I would like to know the answer to. Maybe I just need Express. Maybe I need Standard.

Comment: Do you think that I should make the raised question a separate question here on Stack Overflow? In my opinion we are veering off topic and onto a new ticket, but could stay here too.

Comment: If you aware about disk space, you may ask your potential hosting provider about ability to add extra virtual disk to VPS. If it's possible, than you may move our data(databases or applications files or some other data) to this disk. But you should know which kind of data may grow.

Comment: About SQL editions, I think that Express edition is enough if your main database potentially can't exceed database limitation size(10Gb for SQL 2012 Express). If it's obvious that your database will be more that 10Gb, in this case you should change edition.

Comment: I highly doubt that the database will grow to 10GB in size, as it is no where near that now. Do you know the footprint (disk usage) that each of the editions (Express, Standard, Enterprise) take up? That was not very obvious reading the MSDN requirements page.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know disk usage of all SQL edition. Folder of SQL 2008 Express takes 228 Mb on disk.

Comment: I will move forward with either the standard edition, which requires me to burn a new disk, or the enterprise edition, which I already burnt the disk yesterday. The "free" Express edition is not free. Cirrus charges $50 to install product, which is something that I could do just as easily in which case the other two editions work even better.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31262/discussion-between-oleg-neumyvakin-and-sarah-weinberger)

Comment: I created a "MS SQL and Plesk (Windows)" room in chat. Yes, I saw the recommended SQL room, but the conversation was more on general SQL programming issues, rather than the installation of MS SQL into the server (Plesk in this case) environment, so hence the new room.